# How can I add dos2unix to an Alpine based docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM haproxy:alpine

RUN apk --update add bash && apk --no-cache add dos2unix rsyslog supervisor wget curl ruby which py-setuptools py-pip && pip install awscli && chmod +x /*.sh

COPY *haproxy.cfg /etc/
COPY supervisord.ini /etc/
COPY rsyslog.conf /etc/

COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN dos2unix /entrypoint.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 9999

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.ini"]
```

However, when I build this I get:

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  dos2unix (missing):
    required by: world[dos2unix]
```

I can see the package exists here though:  https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=dos2unix&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll note it's in `testing`, not `main` or `community`.

Comment: Is there a way to force it to accept from testing? Or a way to manually add it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need it? In many cases, `tr -d '\r' <in >out && mv out in` will suffice.

Comment: My line endings are showing up as `^M` though - should I account for both `\r` and `^M` and potentially others?

Comment: `\r` and `^M` are two different ways of visually representing the exact same byte. There's no actual difference between them on-disk, but `\r` is the representation that `tr` will recognize.

Comment: To be entirely clear: The *only* difference between DOS and UNIX text files that `dos2unix` fixes is the distinction between `CRLF` line endings in the former and `LF` line endings in the latter. `\r` and `^M` are two different ways of representing a CR character; some software uses the former, and some the latter (and some do something entirely different, such as `%0D` or `\x0d`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your own link, `dos2unix` is (at this time, February 2017) only in `testing`, not in `main` or `community`. From [the relevant documentation](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management) --

> If you only have the main repository enabled in your configuration, apk will not include packages from the other repositories. To install a package from the edge/testing repository without changing your repository configuration file, use the command below. This will tell apk to use that particular repository.
>
> ```
> apk add cherokee --update-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ --allow-untrusted
> ```

In this case, you would want to substitute `dos2unix` for `cherokee`.

Comment: The package has moved between repositories, so you'll need this command instead: `apk add dos2unix --update-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ --allow-untrusted`